# Why does Luxon DateTime.offset return the opposite value of native Javascript Date.getTimezoneOffset?

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

Is there a specific reason why the Luxon DateTime offset is the opposite of the native JavaScript Date getTimezoneOffset?

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

const luxonOffset = DateTime.now().offset; // -600
const jsDateOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // 600
```

I made a small example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-w4vz2u?file=index.ts

[image]

The screenshot above is from Hawaii timezone...
[image]

I believe that this is the code from Luxon which inverts the offset: https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/zones/systemZone.js#L48-L50

Comment: Always bugged me that utc+ have a negative offset ... probably an american thing... though I guess you add the offset to get to UTC ... as opposed the the offset representing the difference to UTC

Comment: It is a long established convention for offsets to be positive eastward and negative westward of Greenwich to be consistent with lines of longitude. Purely a guess, but I suspect that ECMAScript offsets are the opposite for POSIX compliance. The POSIX family of standards are defined by the American IEEE.

Comment: @JaromandaX—yep. I'm surprised the IEEE didn't define a new prime meridian at -73.935242° and calculate all offsets from there. ;-)